# How the bot's cards containg qnaid and context behave like QnA test?

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

In the test in QnA portal like the below screenshot, those buttons are created by the follow-up prompts from QnA, and when click those buttons, the next Http request contains all the prompts information like text and qnaid. Those the next response will be the answer of the specific qnaid. 
But in the Bot -qnamaker-prompting Sample[enter link description here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/experimental/qnamaker-prompting/csharp_dotnetcore/Helpers/CardHelper.cs), when click the button, the Http request just contain the text as questions, thus the QnA will not get the answer bind with the qnaid. The answer may will not bind with qnaid and just context.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQq8w.png)
So anyone have ideas on how to create a bot like QnA test?

Comment: please click the picture manully, seems i can't upload one picture, just a link

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this is how you can get the same returned results generated from the getAnswers() API call as you get from QnA.

First, pass the current context into getAnswers() (which contains the user's message: "help", "Where did trees come from", "Why is the sky blue?", etc.) and then map the result to a variable:

```js
const stepResults = turnContext.context;
let qnaResults = await this.qnaMaker.getAnswers(stepResults);
```

After validating a response is returned, you can pass the result text into an activity:

```js
await innerDc.prompt('ConfirmPrompt', qnaResults[0].context.prompts[0].displayText);
```

Logging the above qnaResults[0].context.prompts shows the returned prompt values align with request payload seen in devtools:

[image]

[image]

With regards to the sample you linked, the `prompt` value is the returned `QnAPrompts[]` results (i.e. the follow-up prompt). If a prompt is present in the overall QnA results, it is parsed and displayed as a button. The `displayText` is coming from that prompt.

```cs
public static Activity GetHeroCard(string cardTitle, QnAPrompts[] prompts)
{
  var chatActivity = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
  var buttons = new List<CardAction>();

  var sortedPrompts = prompts.OrderBy(r => r.DisplayOrder);
  foreach (var prompt in sortedPrompts)
  {
    buttons.Add(
      new CardAction()
      {
        Value = prompt.DisplayText,
        Type =  ActionTypes.ImBack,
        Title = prompt.DisplayText,
      });
  }

  var plCard = new HeroCard()
  {
    Title = cardTitle,
    Subtitle = string.Empty,
    Buttons = buttons
  };

  var attachment = plCard.ToAttachment();

  chatActivity.Attachments.Add(attachment);

  return (Activity)chatActivity;
}
```

Hope of help!